# Laravel is adding forward slashes to all responses

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a weird issue. Laravel 5.2 is prepending `\` to every single response which is messing up the responses. JSON data is getting returned as `\{"message": ""}` instead of `{"message": ""}` and view responses `\<!DOCTYPE html>` which is causing the `\` to be displayed on the page.

I'm using laravel 5.2 on PHP 5.6.23 (ubuntu server).

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT: This issue is not present on a different server using PHP 5.5.9

EDIT 2: artisian command output are getting prepended with `\`, example: `\Configuration cache cleared!`, `\Route cache cleared!`
`

Comment: Do you have a middleware or anything that accidentally echoes a string `'\\'` ?

Comment: @Loek there are no `'\\'` in any middleware used. I have edited my question to add more information.

Comment: Make sure you are at least showing PHP warnings and in your php.ini file set `output_buffering` to `off` and try running your app again.  It should give you a hint as to what file is outputing text.

Comment: thanks @user3158900 I will do that and see what's up.

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet you have accidentally added '\' in some file before `<?php` or after `?>` This happened to me quite some times, always the same result as you. With some luck you can use find in project and search for `\<?php` and `?>\`

Comment: I updated my questions. This issue is not present on PHP 5.5.9 on a different server. The code is exactly the same on both servers.

Comment: How do you know your code is exactly the same on both servers? How are you comparing the two codebases?

Comment: @toon81 the code is fetched from a git repository. It's the same repository for both servers.

Comment: You're not answering my question.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely somewhere, in some file or another, you have probably echo'ed / printed a '/' is my guess.

I would start with `public/index.php` and comment out everything and then hit that file from the browser, and find no output (hopefully).

If no `/`, slowly uncomment out bits of index.php until you see it pop up again.

Unfortunately, because its such a common character, there is no way to `search all` to find it.